# Page transitions with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply the page transitions to the an HTML page. This page will be on IE. The page has an still image to which I need to apply transitions for the latest IE 9 and above. After a few seconds(some duration) a new image is put in place of the existing image src and the html is loaded again. But in this process I am not able to get the pagebeforehide  or before unload kind of events to apply the transitions and by that time the new page is loaded (though page name is same).

Below is what I tried:

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="0x000000" scroll="no" style="border:none;margin:0px;">
<table width=400 height=400 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td bgcolor="black" align=center valign=middle style="border:none;padding:0px;">
<IMG  id="testimg" src="file:///c:/users/public/pictures/sample pictures/lighthouse.jpg" duration=5000 width=400 height=400 >
</td></tr></table>

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() { 
 var img = document.querySelector('img'); 
 function loaded() { 
  $("#testimg").hide(0).delay(0).fadeIn(1000); 
 }

  function beforeUnload() { 
  $("#testimg").fadeOut(1000);
  }

 });
  if (img.complete) {
 loaded(); 
 }
 else { 
  img.addEventListener('load', loaded); 
  img.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', beforeUnload);
 }
 }); 
 </script></BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have also tried out page transitions from JQuery.net but was not helpful either.

Can someone provide some help or pointers as to what is to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function in JQuery?

Comment: Yes. and since the image is directly seen I have hide the image before applying the transition which is not so good looking.